# Detecting malformed JSON in NodeMCU Lua using sjson.decode()

Tags: json, lua, esp8266, nodemcu, panic

**Using NodeMCU (latest release) on ESP-12S**

I am trying to parse user supplied JSON and do something with it.
However, because the JSON is *user supplied*, I cannot guarantee its validity. So I want to first check if the input JSON is malformed or not, before continuing.

I *was* using the following code:

```lua
function validatejson(input)
    
    if sjson.decode(input) then
        return true
    end

end
```

So a successful example would be:

```lua
x = '{"hello":"world"}'

print(validatejson(x))

--> true
```

and an unsuccessful example would be:

```lua
x = '{"hello":world"}'

print(validatejson(x))

--> nil
```

The above function works, however, when using this in my complied code, it runs into a PANIC error and restarts:

```
 PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API: Incomplete JSON object passed to sjson.decode
```

So, as you'd probably have done as well, I decided to use the `pcall()` function which returns the error as a boolean (false means there was no error in the call):

```lua
function validatejson(input)
    
    if not pcall(sjson.decode(input)) then
        return true
    end

end
```

Still no luck! :(

Any ideas how to successfully detect malformed JSON in Lua using NodeMCU?

Comment: If you are using the `cjson` lua library, then use `local cjson = require "cjson.safe"`. When using `cjson.decode()`, it will return `nil` for un-parsable malformed JSON errors.  This approach will prevent throws.  With `cjson.safe`, it returns a `nil` which you can check as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```lua
    if not pcall(sjson.decode(input)) then
        return true
    end
```

That's wrong: you're only calling `pcall` on the result of `sjson.decode(input)`, so the error will happen before `pcall`. The correct way of doing this is:

```lua
local ok, result = pcall(function()
   return sjson.decode(input)
end)
return ok -- might as well return result here though
```